# Automatically send emails using an Alias

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap, google-groups

I'm creating an app that automatically sends emails to different users of a Google Group, where the email sender is the Google Group address.

The app is written in Python and is using Mandrill to send the emails. The distribution of the emails is working properly, but I need to sender email to be the Google Group. I have it setup as an alias on my Gmail, which allows me to manually select the alias and send emails from the Google Groups address. I am looking for a way to automatically send the emails from the alias without me having to manually send it from Gmail.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code example how to send email via SMTP by using python. You can configure "From" field so it will be used as sender. Please pay attention there are python libraries being used: **smtplib**,  **os** and **email**.

```py
import os
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

msg['Subject'] = "Hello from Mandrill, Python style!"
msg['From']    = "John Doe <john@doe.com>" # Your from name and email address
msg['To']      = "recipient@example.com"

text = "Mandrill speaks plaintext"
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')

html = "<em>Mandrill speaks <strong>HTML</strong></em>"
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

username = os.environ['MANDRILL_USERNAME']
password = os.environ['MANDRILL_PASSWORD']

msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mandrillapp.com', 587)

s.login(username, password)
s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())

s.quit()
```

For more information check this link [How to Send via SMTP with Popular Programming Languages](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582137-How-to-Send-via-SMTP-with-Popular-Programming-Languages)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [`Users.settings.sendAs`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs) resource.

> Settings associated with a send-as alias, which can be either the
>   primary login address associated with the account or a custom "from"
>   address. Send-as aliases correspond to the ["Send Mail As"](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370) feature in
>   the web interface.

```
{
  "sendAsEmail": string,
  "displayName": string,
  "replyToAddress": string,
  "signature": string,
  "isPrimary": boolean,
  "isDefault": boolean,
  "treatAsAlias": boolean,
  "smtpMsa": {
    "host": string,
    "port": integer,
    "username": string,
    "password": string,
    "securityMode": string
  },
  "verificationStatus": string
}
```

The `sendAsEmail` property of this resource stands for the email address that appears in the "From:" header for mail sent using this alias. This is read-only for all operations except create.

For other information about managing aliases, you can check out this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/alias_and_signature_settings).